# How to fill up a Data.Map in a space&time efficient way

Tags: performance, haskell, dictionary

Coming back to Haskell four years after the first glimpse of it. I'm always as amazed by the expressiveness, and as baffled by my inability to predict space/time performance.

As a warm up, I took to translating a tiny toy program I had written in C++. It's about "cheating" at Scrabble. You input your game, and it outputs possible words you may play, with your letters alone or by crossing a letter on the board.

The whole thing revolves around a dictionary that's preloaded at start up. The words are then stored as lists in a map, together with their anagrams. The keys are strings of sorted letters. An example will speak more clearly :

```
Key : "AEHPS"  Value : ["HEAPS","PHASE","SHAPE"]
```

The C++ version reads the ~320000 words of the dictionary one at a time, in about 200ms in total. The resulting data structure is a hash-map stored in a `array<99991, vector<string>>` and takes up about 12 megabytes of memory.

The Haskell version reads the same dictionary in about 5 seconds, and the program heap size was ballooning up to 400 megabytes ! I changed the value type in the `Data.Map` from `[String]` to `[ByteString]` to save some memory, and that brought the program memory consumption down to roughly 290 megabytes. That's still 24 times more than my C++ version. That's more than mere "overhead", even though `Data.Map` is a tree instead of an array.

So I assume that I'm doing something wrong.

The whole module is visible here : (deprecated link)

I suppose that my trouble has something to do with the way that `Data.Map` gets built incrementally, growing upon previous versions of itself ? Or with the data structure itself ? Or something else ?

I'll try other solutions, like `Data.HashMap`, or filling up `Data.Map` with `fromListWith`. Nevertheless, I'd like to build up some understanding of what's going on here. Thanks a lot for any insight !

---

Short answer :

Using Data.Map.Strict, forcing the evaluation of value elements, and storing the keys as ByteStrings too made the miracle of dividing the memory footprint nearly by 3. The result is 100Meg, which is only twice larger than a standard `std::multimap<std::string, std::string>` in C++ for the same dataset. No speedup though. Git updated.

Thanks a lot to all who contributed, there is interesting material down here !

Comment: Also, you use a ByteString for storing, but you read first each line into a string. Use the ByteString file operations to read directly from byte string. Or better, use Text since you have text data, and Text also provide file IO operations.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no good reason to enable line buffering on a file.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using `M.insertWith (++) (sort word) [B.pack word] dict` instead of `let !packed = B.pack word in adjust (packed :) (sort word) dict`? I don't know if `adjust` will be more efficient in this context, but it at least seems to communicate the intention better.

Comment: No particular reason. It's my second program in Haskell that's more than 5 lines long (first one was four years ago) and I'm still absolutely unfamiliar with both library and idioms. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One mistake that you are making that hasn't been pointed out yet is that you are storing unevaluated thunks of the form `B.pack word` in the lists that are the values in your Map. That means that you are retaining essentially the entire input file in the inefficient String format during the construction of your Map, at a cost of 24 bytes per character in your input file. Using the `Data.Map.Strict` API makes no difference here, since the functions in that API only force the elements of the Map to weak head normal form, which for a list means only evaluating whether the outermost constructor is `[]` or `(:)`, and not evaluating any of the list's elements.

Another improvement you can make is to use the [`ShortByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Short.html) type available in recent versions of bytestring (the one that comes with GHC 7.8 is new enough). This is specifically designed for minimizing memory usage when storing many short bytestrings, with the trade-off being that most operations on a `ShortByteString` require a copy.

András Kovács's Map example code would look like this with these changes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Short as B (ShortByteString, toShort, fromShort)

shortPack = B.toShort . B.pack

main = do
  words <- lines <$> readFile "dict.txt"
  print $ M.size $
    M.fromListWith (++) $ map (\w -> let !x = shortPack w in (shortPack $ sort w, [x])) words
```

Each of these changes saves about 30% of the maximum residency in my tests, for a total of over 50% space usage savings.

Comment: Laziness kills... Hell I hadn't thought of that. Got bitten again... As for the short byte string, thanks for the hint. I didn't know that type. That doesn't help understand how the Map eats up so much space in itself, but it defintely helps improve things while keep the same data structure.

Comment: Very nice, and I think this is the proper direct answer. I wonder what I should do with my botched benchmarking.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**: Removed erroneous benchmarking and commentary, only left a minor bit of advice. See Reid Barton's answer for a direct solution to OP's question.

If you don't need to change the dictionary at runtime, then [DAWG-s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton) are pretty much the most space-time efficient solution you can get (at least for word games).

For example, we can generate and serialize a DAWG from your dictionary that takes only 295 Kb space, and supports quite efficient lookup and prefix matching:

```
import qualified Data.DAWG.Packed as D -- from my "packed-dawg" package

main = do
  words <- lines <$> readFile "dict.txt"
  D.toFile "dict.dawg" $ D.fromList words -- serialize as "dict.dawg"
```

Comment: I didn't realize `Data.Trie` was an uncompressed trie. Blech.

Comment: Also, you should mention that you are the author of `packed-dawg`.

Comment: Before diving into all those answers as a whole, here's the C++ version (don't mind the `using namespace` that's gone astray into a header...). 12 Mb as per the activity monitor, on a 64 bit OSX. :) gist.github.com/anonymous/1596f091109238a9ee22 unordered_map used four times as much memory indeed, hence the array of vectors of strings, with a bit less than 100000 elements.

Comment: No time right now for more playing around (home, kid, dinner...), but the DAWG package seems to be a very nice thing. Thanks for that lead.
I'm still very dubious though about a Data.Map needing 290 Mb to store 320000 entries in the original solution. That's about one kilobyte per entry. How can one explain that ?

Comment: @MathiasDolidon: Your custom container, plus your handling of hash collisions, plus small string optimization (maybe...) together make the 12 Mb space plausbile, indeed. I'll probably look at the Data.Map thing later, and try to get more precise numbers on space (keyword: `ghc-datasize`).

Comment: @dfeuer: `Data.Trie` does have compressed arcs, so I reworded my answer.

Comment: Given Reid Barton's answer, I've "unaccepted" your answer ; I hope you forgive this rudeness, nevertheless your input has been highly appreciated, and I'll definitely have a look at DAWG ; with my regards.

Answer (score 2):

The following works in around a second on my laptop:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import Data.List

type Dict = M.Map T.Text [T.Text]

newDict = M.empty

addWord:: T.Text -> Dict -> Dict
addWord word dict = M.insertWith (++) (T.pack $ sort $ T.unpack word) [word] dict

loadAnagramsFromFile fileName = do
    full <- T.readFile fileName
    let ls = T.lines full
    return $ foldr addWord newDict lsct ls
```

This is using Text, with just a wart for sorting. There may be a better way of sorting a Text.

Comment: Since Scrabble only needs a tiny portion of ASCII (plus blanks) `Text` seems like overkill to me.

Comment: Even if you wanted multilingual support, you'd only ever be dealing with one language at a time, and no character-based writing systems (as those wouldn't really work for the game). So any suitable writing system could be managed with `ByteString` using some 8-bit encoding or other.

Comment: Indeed. An Scrabble is a hard thing if you want to go multlingual. Thinking of the Spanish version for instance, that has LL and CH tokens, besides L, C and H. But this is only a toy, so I'll be fine with either ByteString or Text. The factor in size does not account for how much memory this Data.Map takes up. :)

Comment: Just tried. No speed improvement on my laptop readFile + foldr. It's seven years old, good hardware for writing fast programs. ;) But the code looks much nicer.